# How can I get HDMI and VGA to work properly after GRUB menu?

Tags: hdmi

When I boot up and choose Ubuntu (I use dual boot, also I run dual screen setup), the VGA and HDMI do not configure properly when HDMI is plugged in. If HDMI is not plugged in the VGA works fine. How can I fix this issue?

output results for Marmayogi
List of supported video modes:
Legend: mask/position=red/green/blue/reserved
Adapter "cirrusCLGD5446PCI
Video Driver:
no info available
Adapter 'VESABIOS Extension Video Driver:
VBE info: version 3.0 OEM software rev:1.0
total memory:65472KiB 0*160  848*480*8 (896) palletted
0*161 848*480*16 (1728) Direct color, mask:5/6/5/0 pos:11/5/0/0
*0 *162 848*480*32 (3392) Direct color, mask:8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24 Edit version 1.3
preferred mode 1360*768 Adapter VGA Driver: no info available

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"` 2. `xrandr` and 3. `pulseaudio --check -v`

Comment: Why do I have to edit my question? It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Before attempting to solve your problem, I need to know about  HDMI port(s), and other ports such as VGA or DP that your system supports. Are they alive or disconnected? What are the default and recommended screen resolutions? Are drivers up and running? HDMI carries not only video but also audio. So the state of audio daemon should also be known. @Mike Peterson, if it is pretty straight forward then why is the system not behaving as you expected?

Comment: @MikePeterson And you're asking for help as a new user to this site...  Surely, if you want your problem solved, you should do whatever is necessary to make it easier for the people whose help you're asking from...

Comment: Does your external monitor have DP (Display port)? If so, please connect your computer with external monitor through DP instead of HDMI and test whether it works. Please report.

Comment: My secondary screen  is a flat screen which is hdmi it is not a monitor. i have to diconnect the HDMI at startup or else VGA and HDMI does not configure. after startup I can plug in HDMI and it works. How do I know if my drivers are up and running? And what do you mean by state of the art daemon should also be known? @Marmayogi

Comment: When HDMI and VGA are connected together during startup, are the drivers up and running? That is exactly what we are going to find out @MikePeterson. Before that, we should make sure that VGA driver is up and running as well audio Daemon **under normal conditions**. The sound data is carried over the same wire as video in the various video blanking intervals. So the video driver has to communicate with the audio driver about the current video mode and so on. This also should be investigated during start up.

Comment: Your description of problem as **the VGA and HDMI do not configure properly when HDMI is plugged in** is NOT enough @MikePeterson. Please explain exactly what happened when you restart the computer with HDMI plugged in with secondary screen. i.e. both HDMI and VGA together. After reaching GRUB menu, you choose Ubuntu to boot. Did you see Ubuntu login screen in both Primary as well as Secondary screens? Or did you see blank screen on primary and login screen on secondary? Or did  you stuck during the interval between Grub and login? Please describe exactly your observation. Thanks.

Comment: In GRUB menu, If HDMI is plugged in Ubuntu screen only appears on HDMI and VGA is blank, then zooms in too close after boot is complete and HDMI is still black. I appreciate your help. @ Marmayogi

Comment: After completion of boot process **which one was blank**? You said that in the beginning of boot process, ubuntu screen appeared **only on HDMI** and NOT on VGA. You concluded that after completion, **HDMI is still black** which I take as a `typographical` error. I understand that **it is VGA** which was blank right from the beginning until end. @MikePeterson, please confirm this **typo** error. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the output of the commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` 2. `cat /proc/cmdline` and 3 `sudo grep -i kms /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Thanks.

Comment: There is no typo. If HDMI is pluged in VGA is blank at GRUB and HDMI shows GRUB but is blank after complete boot and VGA is zoomed in too close.  There is no typographical error.  Outputs are as follows 1:  ="quiet splash"   2: cat: invalid option -- 'i'  .     I did copy and paste commands by the way.  Thank You,  @Marmayogi

Comment: Output of the three commands were not yet posted. Please do so. The commands are: 1. `cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` 2. `cat /proc/cmdline` and 3. `sudo grep -i kms /var/log/Xorg.*.log`.Thanks.

Comment: I already posted output of commands if you would simply read the last post however I probably messed up on the second and third commands as i entered them as one line. Outputs are 1  ="quiet splash"    2   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic root=UUID=591432a3-228d-445b-8866-c93e5aa60ico ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1     3   grep: /var/log/Xorg.*.log: No such file or directory                Thank you for your patience @Marmayogi

Comment: Restart the computer and press `shift` key to reach GRUB menu. Type `c` and enter into GRUB command line. You will see `grub >` prompt. Enter `videoinfo` and please **post the output** by editing your question. **Note:** You can  test and see the screen display of each resolution shown by `videoinfo`  using command `grub > videotest`. For example `grub > videotest 1024x768`. To get out of `videotest` mode, hit `Ctrl+Alt+Del`.

Comment: I have posted the output by editing my question. @Marmayogi

Comment: Somebody please respond! It has been 11 days and nobody wants to help me any further.

Comment: I have posted the output for the command suggested and have been waiting since may 27th what do I do next?